# How do I convert a .png file to a multi-part file?

Tags: python, python-requests, png

I have a .png file that I am pulling from a server, and I want to post that file to another server using an API which calls for a multi-part file as its parameter. Are .png files already considered multi-part, or do I need to manipulate the response data in some way?

Comment: Have you tested the process? Does the API accept the file? If so, does that answer your question, or if not, what errors are you getting? Please provide more detail about what you have tried and what has not worked (if anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the HTML multipart form: *multipart* is the format of the HTTP request body. It has nothing to do with the file itself. You need to build a request like

```
POST /test.html HTTP/1.1 
Host: target.org 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary="ABCD" 

--ABCD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="my_file"; filename="example.txt" 

<<put the actual binary data of the file here>>
```

You can build it manually, but the libraries you are using would probably provide some easier way (you don't say what you are using, so it's impossible to  tell)

Comment: I am using requests.py

Comment: Haven't done it, but http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/ has a section "POST a multipart file".

Comment: I've read the section, my real issue I think is that I am unsure how to turn the content of a GET request into a file that can be opened.  That is I am trying to do this:    r1 = request.get('url 1')  content = r.content  r2 = request.post('url 2', files={'my_file.png' : content})

Comment: ^^ Sorry about the formatting, new to this site and haven't figured out how to make things look nice yet

Comment: That depends on what the request body contains. Most probably, it will contain a dict, with the file contents somewhere. The request, *does not* contain a file, it contains the *contents* of the file. You take the contents and write them to a file (or, in your case, you can directly post them to the other API url)